# Apache not Starting : (98)Address already in use

Tags: apache, centos, webmin

Yesterday my WordPress sites went offline showing the error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.  Today i discovered Apache is turned off in my VPS. Starting Apache, my Control panel returns:

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
 httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-12-23 17:05:28 UTC; 7min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 7728 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 7727 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 7727 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 23 17:05:27 site.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Dec 23 17:05:28 site.com httpd[7727]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443 (hidden ip)
Dec 23 17:05:28 site.com httpd[7727]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Dec 23 17:05:28 site.com httpd[7727]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Dec 23 17:05:28 site.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 23 17:05:28 site.com kill[7728]: kill: cannot find process ""
Dec 23 17:05:28 site.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 23 17:05:28 site.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 23 17:05:28 site.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Dec 23 17:05:28 site.com systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

I tried to discover what services are running on port, to kill them, but ports 80 and 443 are not being used.

By specifically querying these ports, they return:

```
80/tcp closed http
443/tcp closed https
```

Even with doors closed, error occurs when trying to start apache service. I searched Stack Overflow answers, tried all of  answer methods on these question, but nothing solved the problem.

I'm using updated `Webmin` on `CentOS` 7.7.1908

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command to check if port 443 is used by another service:

```
netstat -tunlp | grep 443
```

If there is no output, make sure that the `Listen 443` directive is not set multiple times in the Apache virtual host directories of your domains.

Comment: I already tried to check 80 and 443 ports. And only 1 line in the Apache virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and I opened this file:

> /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

and saw these 2 lines:

```
Listen 443 https
Listen MY_IP:443
```

I just commented the first line, like this:

```
# Listen 443 https
Listen MY_IP:443
```

and everything went to normal. I was able to start the httpd service.

`systemctl start httpd.service`